# alevel implicit differentiation question

Tags: derivatives

I'm stuck on this implicit differentiation question, where I'm required to find the turning points, the equation goes like this y^3+3xy^2-x^3=3

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by turning points, but to find the derivative of your implicit function,

$$\mathrm dy3y^2+3y^2\mathrm dx+6yx\mathrm dy-3x^2\mathrm dx=0\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{3x^2-3y^2}{3y^2+6xy}$$
Solving for $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ as you would any other variable.

Comment: Well, it seems that turning points are points of extrema of either $y(x)$, or $x(y)$. Therefore, one should equate $y'(x)$ to $0$, getting $(1,1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1)$. Of these, only $(1,1)$ is on the original curve. It remains to check whether $y'(x)$ changes sign when passing through $1$. A similar analysis should then be carried over for $x(y)$.

Comment: How did u get 3y^2dx where I got 3x^2dy instead?

Comment: where do you mean? I made an error in the constant on the yx term but otherwise the above is correct